# Count input without spaces, commas, or periods - Java

Tags: java, loops

Input is "Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userText;
      int numPun = 0; //number of punctiation and spaces
      // Add more variables as needed
   
      userText = scnr.nextLine();  // Gets entire line, including spaces. 

     for (int i = 0; i < userText.length(); i++){
        if ((userText.charAt(i) != ' ') && (userText.charAt(i) != ',') && (userText.charAt(i) != '.'));{
           numPun++;
        }
     }
     System.out.println(numPun);
   }
}
```

My current output is to 29, which is the total amount of characters in the whole line. Expected output is supposed to be 21. Where am i going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Stray semicolon terminating `if`, and use `&&` NOT `||`

<sup>In a previous version of this answer I specified to use `||` instead of `&&`. DO NOT do that. Kudos to [Basil Bourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727954/count-input-without-spaces-commas-or-periods-java/66727985#66728178) for being the first one to point that out.</sup>

Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userText.length(); i++){
    char current = userText.charAt(i);
    if (current  != ' ' && current  != ',' && current  != '.'){
       numPun++;
    }
 }
```

You have an extra `;` after the `if` statement expression.

See it [in action](https://ideone.com/WM40Au)

**Explanation:**

In the previous version of this answer the expression `current  != ' ' || current  != ',' || current  != '.'` is equal to `if current is not a space or is not a comma or is not a period do this:`.

That meant that if the character was a comma, it would add 1 to `numPun`, because it was not a space.

In the new expression, it is equal to `if current is not a space and is not a comma and is not a period`. Therefore it would first check whether it was a space, then a comma, then a period.

Comment: I just tried this and to no avail - still output 29. Is it not adding to my int "numPun" and just outputting the length?

Comment: @MattTrembley What's your test case?

Comment: Testing with "Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down." as well as "abcd,,,,efgh....ijkl    ...." but the second one should come with the first. I hope thats what you meant.

Comment: @MattTrembley Sorry! I've found the logic issue. It works now.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @MattTrembley If my answer answers the question, please consider accepting!

Answer (score 2):

## Stray semicolon yes, but `||` no

As [Answer by Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66727985/642706) correctly says, you have stray semicolon to fix.

But the instruction to use `||` is incorrect.

Here is your code, corrected.

```java
String input = "Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down.";

int countLetters = 0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++ )
{
    char c = input.charAt( i );
    //System.out.println( "c = " + c );
    if ( ( c != ' ' ) && ( c != ',' ) && ( c != '.' ) )
    {
        countLetters++;
    }
}
System.out.println( "countLetters = " + countLetters );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/LYDDkW).

> 21

I would have written such code by using a `List` of forbidden characters rather than a series of equality tests.

```java
String input = "Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down.";
List < String > nonLetters = List.of( " " , "," , "." );
int countLetters = 0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++ )
{
    char c = input.charAt( i );
    System.out.println( "c = " + c );
    if ( ! nonLetters.contains( String.valueOf( c ) ) )
    {
        countLetters++;
    }
}
System.out.println( "countLetters = " + countLetters );
```

Even better: Use code points rather than `char` type.

## Code points, not `char`

The `char` type is obsolete in Java. That type is a relic, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Instead, work with [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number to represent each character. Unicode assigns one integer number to each of its 143,859 characters. The code points range from zero to over a million, most being unassigned.

The [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class can return an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of the code point number for each character. Convert that `IntStream` to an array of `int` numbers. Loop the array. For each code point number, ask if the character Unicode assigns to that number [is considered a letter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)) or not. If a letter, increment our count.

```
String input = "Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down.";

int countLetters = 0;

int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
for ( int codePoint : codePoints )
{
    if ( Character.isLetter( codePoint ) )
    {
        countLetters++;
    }
}
System.out.println( "countLetters = " + countLetters );
```

> 21

### Stream

We can even go so far as to make a one-liner using Java stream and lambda features.

```java
long countLetters = 
    "Listen, Mr. Jones, calm down."
    .codePoints()
    .filter( 
        ( int codePoint ) -> Character.isLetter( codePoint ) 
    )
    .count()
;
```

> 21

Comment: Very astute on spotting to use `&&`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! As I am currently just getting into programming and only have taken Python and Java introductory courses, the information you provided is to an extent over my head. But with "The char type is obsolete in Java. That type is a relic, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode." I find interesting and I hope my current course works explains this more

Comment: @MattTrembley For background, read this post: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 0):

(userText.charAt(i) != ' ') || (userText.charAt(i) != ',') || (userText.charAt(i) != '.')

Answer (score 0):

also, missing the && (c != '!')) which was counting all extra exclamations and failing the tests.

completed code as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userText;
      userText = scnr.nextLine();
      String input = userText; 

  
int countLetters = 0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++ )
{
    char c = input.charAt( i );

    if ( ( c != ' ' ) && ( c != ',' ) && ( c != '.' ) && (c != '!' ) && (c != 
'!' ))
    {
        countLetters++;
    }
}
System.out.println(countLetters );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that satisfies all the questions in zyBooks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2gp7.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, keep it simple.

```
  int output;

  userText = scnr.nextLine();  // Gets entire line, including spaces. 
  
  userText = userText.replace(" ", "");
  userText = userText.replace(".", "");
  userText = userText.replace("!", "");
  userText = userText.replace(",", "");
  output = userText.length();
  System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Often, the best first step is to simplify the problem: if rephrased, it can become “how many words characters are there?”, which can be expressed in code as “how long is the input after removing all non-word chars:

```
int count = userText.replaceAll("\\W", "").length();
```

being just one line of code, there are less lances for bugs to hide.